# why is the WebView.evaluateJavascript method called twice?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, evaluatejavascript

public static String dataFromJs;

```
public void androidMethod() {
    // initialize static String dataFromJs.
    dataFromJs = "";
    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:jsFuction();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(s));
            reader.setLenient(true);
            try {
                if (reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
                    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                        // get string value from javascript and I want to use the value
                        dataFromJs = reader.nextString();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "MainActivity: IOException", e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // NOOP
                }
            }
        }
    });

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if(url.endsWith("menu/page.do")) {
                androidMethod();
                // do something with dataFromJs..
            }
    }
```

---

The androidMethod is my method in android.
I try to use the str what I receieved from javascript.
but  webView.evaluateJavascript method always return null at the first time,
the  webView.evaluateJavascript is called again and return string value correctly.

Since the return value is null at the first time, so I can't use the androidMethod in another method.

Anyone has good solution??

is it have something to do with this log (The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.) ?

Thank you!

Comment: Show your other code that does the calling

Comment: I edited the code. The overrided method onReceiveValue has only return type void, so I try to use publice static String dataFromJs . 

I want to use the value from javascript after puting dataFromJs but  evaluateJavascript return null and not be called callback onReceiveValue   at first time. Then error occur in 

if(url.endsWith("menu/page.do")) {
   androidMethod();
   // do something with dataFromJs but error ocurr since dataFromJs ""
}

Comment: I found out my problem was evaluateJavascript is Asyn. But is there no way to make common method with evaluateJavascript? I think its to hassle to wirte evaluateJavascript every when i get data from javascript.